# Can't resolve AnimatedGifEncoder in my Android project

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I've been trying to develop an App for the past few months and have used the Glide module just fine without any problems. I'm looking to create an aminated gif from an array of bitmaps and found a code sample that uses the [AnimatedGifEncoder](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/380/com/bumptech/glide/gifencoder/AnimatedGifEncoder.html#AnimatedGifEncoder()) class that should be part of the glide libraries.

Somehow, when I try and use the class, my IDE doesn't seem to be able to find it. I've been using Glide to load images just fine, so I'm just totally stumped as to why this one particular class can't be found.

My App level build.gradle:
`implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'`

I've used the Glide.with() at several places in my code, and it works perfectly. It's just that every time I try and use AnimatedGifEncoder, it just can't seem to find it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It exists in old version Glide **v3.8.0** as newer version excludes JAR for this module that includes `AnimatedGifEncoder` class as per below code snippet in [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/)

```
static def getAndroidPathsForJar() {
    [':library', ':third_party:disklrucache', ':third_party:gif_decoder']
}
```

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/glide/build.gradle

So use old version **v3.8.0** instead of this new version **v4.14.2** to be able to find the required class `AnimatedGifEncoder` and try your sample as below

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
```

Comment: Thanks, Youssef. As I looked more into this, I realized that the good people at Glide have, for whatever reason, hidden a few classes as well as methods within some classes (for instance, it appears that getDecoder() was public in earlier versions of the library, but is now private). I'm loathe to change the library version back, because who knows what state that lib will be in; I guess I'll just have to find a different way to skin that cat. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```kotlin
implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:gifencoder-integration:4.9.0")
```

into your gradle file. The gif encoder has become external since glide 4.